# Graph Making application using OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, graph, quartz-2d

I created my own application which works with graphs of math functions using Quartz2D. It is working pretty fast on new devices, but there are some lags on iphone 3g (Not so noticeable, but still). So, I thought, maybe rewriting my codes using OpenGL ES could help.
I am using primitive graphics, like lines or circles. Is there much difference between these approaches?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is difficulty. OpenGL ES only gives you vertices to work with so you'll end up spending a lot of time recreating what Quartz 2D already does.